# id for categories and products

Tags: php

Is it possible to write code in functions.php that retrieves the tag_id of a product category and assigns the product to that category based on the tag_id field for the product?

I want to use tag_id because I have many subcategories with the same names, so I can't add products based on the name.

If using tag_id is not possible, can I create a custom ID for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I have updated it with a hook for when you save the product, try saving a product and see if it assigns everything correctly

```
add_action('save_post_product', 'wpb_assign_product_to_categories_on_save');

function wpb_assign_product_to_categories_on_save($post_id) {
    // Check if this is a valid call
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) 
        return;

    // Check the user's permissions
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
        return;

    // Call the function to assign product to categories
    wpb_assign_product_to_matching_category($post_id);
}

function wpb_assign_product_to_matching_category($post_id) {
    // Retrieve the custom id for this product
    $product_custom_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_id', true);

    if (!empty($product_custom_id)) {
        $categories = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ));

        $matching_category_ids = array();

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            // Retrieve the custom id for this category
            $category_custom_id = get_term_meta($category->term_id, 'custom_id', true);

            // Check if the product's custom id matches the category's custom id
            if ($product_custom_id === $category_custom_id) {
                $matching_category_ids[] = $category->term_id;
            }
        }

        // Assign the product to the matching categories
        if (!empty($matching_category_ids)) {
            wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $matching_category_ids, 'product_cat');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Now if i update product it goes correct product category. I also tested importing a product with a custom ID using a CSV file. It automatically went under the correct category. Big thanks!

Comment: Awesome, please give the correct code an up vote so everyone else can tell which one it is. The trick was getting the hook right. Happy coding!

Comment: This is the correct code, but i tried to up vote this and it says:” Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.”

Comment: No worries, as long as it works I am happy

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is certainly possible to do what you are speaking of. First we retrieve the tag_id for the product, then assign the product to a category  using this ID. WooCommerce uses custom taxonomies like product_cat for categories, so you would use WordPress functions to set the terms for the product.
This code assumes you have a way to get the tag_id for each product (perhaps from a custom field or an external source).

```
function wpb_assign_product_category() {
    // Get all products
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1 // Adjust this as needed
    );

    $products = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        // Assuming you have a way to get the tag_id for each product
        $tag_id = get_post_meta($product->ID, 'your_custom_field_for_tag_id', true);

        // Check if tag_id is valid and then assign the product to this category
        if (!empty($tag_id) && term_exists($tag_id, 'product_cat')) {
            wp_set_post_terms($product->ID, array($tag_id), 'product_cat');
        }
    }
}

// You can call this function where it makes sense in your context,
// or you can hook it into WordPress initialization if it needs to run automatically.
```

If your tag_id field is a comma separated list of categories you can do it like this:

```
function wpb_assign_product_category() {
    // Get all products
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1 // Adjust this as needed
    );

    $products = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        // Retrieve the comma-separated list of tag_ids for each product
        $tag_ids = get_post_meta($product->ID, 'your_custom_field_for_tag_id', true);

        // Check if tag_ids is not empty
        if (!empty($tag_ids)) {
            // Split the tag_ids into an array
            $tag_id_array = explode(',', $tag_ids);

            // Initialize an array to store valid term IDs
            $valid_term_ids = array();

            // Check each tag_id and add to the array if valid
            foreach ($tag_id_array as $tag_id) {
                if (term_exists(trim($tag_id), 'product_cat')) {
                    $valid_term_ids[] = trim($tag_id);
                }
            }

            // Assign the product to these categories
            if (!empty($valid_term_ids)) {
                wp_set_post_terms($product->ID, $valid_term_ids, 'product_cat');
            }
        }
    }
}

// You can call this function where it makes sense in your context.
```

Comment: Thanks! I have now created a field "custom id" for product categories and same ”custom id” field for products that can be saved. Is it possible to modify your code so that it looks for the category and the product with the corresponding custom id and adds the product to that category?

Thank you so much for the quick response.

Comment: I posted the solution above. If you like my answers please give them an upvote :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question:**

> > "I have now created a field "custom id" for product categories and same ”custom id” field for products that can be saved. Is it possible to modify your code so that it looks for the category and the product with the corresponding custom id and adds the product to that category? "

Yes, here is the code :

1. Retrieve the custom id for each product: Extract the custom id from the product's metadata.
2. Find the category with the matching custom id: You will need to search through the product categories to find the one(s) that have the same custom id as the product.
3. Assign the product to the matching category: Once you have the IDs of the matching categories, assign the product to those categories.

```
function wpb_assign_product_to_matching_category() {
    // Get all products
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1 // Adjust this as needed
    );

    $products = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        // Retrieve the custom id for this product
        $product_custom_id = get_post_meta($product->ID, 'product_custom_id', true);

        if (!empty($product_custom_id)) {
            $categories = get_terms(array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'hide_empty' => false,
            ));

            $matching_category_ids = array();

            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                // Retrieve the custom id for this category
                $category_custom_id = get_term_meta($category->term_id, 'category_custom_id', true);

                // Check if the product's custom id matches the category's custom id
                if ($product_custom_id === $category_custom_id) {
                    $matching_category_ids[] = $category->term_id;
                }
            }

            // Assign the product to the matching categories
            if (!empty($matching_category_ids)) {
                wp_set_post_terms($product->ID, $matching_category_ids, 'product_cat');
            }
        }
    }
}

// You can call this function where it makes sense in your context.
```

Comment: I put the code in the functions.php file, but it doesn’t work. The problem is probably that in product categories, it's named 'custom_id,' and in products, it's also named 'custom_id' (the field has the same name)?

Comment: Make sure you put that custom ID in the code, I'm sure you did right?

Comment: In the code it says product_custom_id and category_custon_id. I'm assuming you changed both of those to custom_id correct,? Also how did you create the custom fields?

Comment: Make sure to clear your cache, upload the file again, things like that. Basically make sure the codes actually running.

Comment: Yes, i changed both to ”custom_id” and it didn’t work. I created those custom id fields with chatgpt. I asked to make code to functions.php file which will create custom id fields to product categories and products.  I can now save custom id for example custom id:123 to products and categories.

Comment: Is it easier to create new code for custom fields and after that add code which you already created?

Comment: How are you creating the custom fields? Are you using code if so post the code here.

Comment: I posted it below. I don't know why the code doesn't display correctly underneath, but you can still see what it contains. And with that code, the custom ID fields appeared in the right places, and I was able to save the information in them.

Comment: I don't see the code, probably does not come through unless you escape it with the backtics
```
echo 'asdfads';
```

Comment: I added new answer because code didn’t fit to this comment section. Do you see code now?

Comment: Link to code: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/421624/238973

Comment: Try this:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/421625/238918

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code (custom id):

````
function save_custom_id_for_product_category($term_id) {
    $custom_id = isset($_POST['custom_id']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom_id']) : '';

    // Check that custom ID is set before saving
    if (!empty($custom_id)) {
        update_term_meta($term_id, 'custom_id', $custom_id);
    }
}

// Add field to admin panel for product category
function add_custom_id_field_to_product_category() {
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="custom_id">Custom ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="custom_id" id="custom_id" value="">
        <p class="description">Add custom ID for the product category.</p>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// Display saved information in product category admin panel
function display_custom_id_in_product_category_edit($term) {
    $custom_id = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'custom_id', true);
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row"><label for="custom_id">Custom ID</label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="custom_id" id="custom_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr($custom_id); ?>">
            <p class="description">This is the custom ID for the product category.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

// Save custom ID for product category on creation and edit
add_action('created_product_cat', 'save_custom_id_for_product_category');
add_action('edited_product_cat', 'save_custom_id_for_product_category');

// Add field for product category addition
add_action('product_cat_add_form_fields', 'add_custom_id_field_to_product_category');

// Add field for product category editing
add_action('product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'display_custom_id_in_product_category_edit');

// Save custom ID for product
function save_custom_id_for_product($post_id) {
    $custom_id = isset($_POST['custom_id']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom_id']) : '';

    // Check that custom ID is set before saving
    if (!empty($custom_id)) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_id', $custom_id);
    }
}

// Remove field from product addition
remove_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_custom_id_field_to_product');

// Display saved information in product edit panel
function display_custom_id_in_product_edit() {
    global $post;
    $custom_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_id', true);
    ?>
    <div class="options_group">
        <p class="form-field">
            <label for="custom_id">Custom ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="short" name="custom_id" id="custom_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr($custom_id); ?>">
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// Save custom ID for product on save
add_action('save_post_product', 'save_custom_id_for_product');

// Add field for product editing
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'display_custom_id_in_product_edit'); ```
````